# "If I am given this opportunity" vs "If this opportunity is given to me"

Tags: phrase-choice

> 1. If I am given this opportunity, I will be successful.

> 2. If this opportunity is given to me, I will be successful.

Are they both correct?

Which one is more appropriate in a formal writing?

Comment: Both are grammatically correct, but (1) is more idiomatic; indeed, the words _if I am_ are often omitted.

Comment: @KateBunting Is omission of _"if I am"_ , i.e., _"given this opportunity, I will be successful."_ formal?

Comment: _Given the opportunity, I would readily [do that]_ is a very common usage, and would be acceptable in formal writing. I'm not sure how you _know_ you are going to succeed at something.